Why don't the images in my mail templates display when the message is opened with Apple mail on iPad or iPhone?
I added images to my message template. The images appear properly when viewed in GMail on my desktop or iPhone but they are replaces by a blue square with a question mark in it when the message is opened with the iPhone Mail program. In the settings on the iPhone Mail program: "Protect Mail Activity" is not enabled and "Block All Remote Content" is not enabled.
Why don't the images display on the iPhone when opened with the iPhone Mail app? Is there a change I can make to the template that will enable the images to display properly in the iPhone Mail app?
CiviCRM 5.66.0 on WordPress Version 6.5
Here is the introductory part of the HTML that references the image that appears as a question mark in a blue box when viewed with the Apple mail app on an iPhone.
<p><img alt="" src="https://torontorailwaymuseum.com/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/Screenshot%20TRHA%20Letterhead%281%29.jpg" style="width: 762px; height: 157px;" /></p>

<p>{domain.now}</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>To whom it may concern:</p>

I am using the Mosaico editor, Version 3.3.1697392242

Could you please edit your question to include the HTML that causes the blue square with question mark?  What editor are you using to create the mail?  If you haven't changed anything, it would be CKEditor4, but other possible answers are "Mosaico", "CKEditor5", and "Summernote".  Looking at *Administer > System Settings > Extensions can tell you if any of those are installed.

you should enclose the HTML in a "backtick fence".  The "backtick" is the (`) character.  Put three on their own line, hit enter, paste your HTML, then another line with only three backticks.  Everything inside the "fence" should show up "literally", without being interpreted.

That's perfectly good HTML.  Sorry I don't have a better answer but there's nothing that looks incorrect there.

as a good practice, I avoid any empty space character in any file name: Screenshot TRHA Letterhead(1).jpg. Have you tried with renaming the file?

Thanks. I just tried renaming the file and found no change - the jpg displays properly in Gmail on the iPhone but not when opened with the Apple mail program on iPhone.

If you try this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+box+for+image+in+apple+mail
you'll see you're not alone! You have a symptom with multiple possible source issues, and for that you should blame apple's iphone mail program.
You could try futzing blindly like we all do under such circumstances, but let's be clear that a device that fails to operate appropriately and provides no way of understanding why is fundamentally wrong.
Unlike a good old train!
